# Bigquery's UDFs: how to load a jQuery library with javascript UDFs?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I'm trying to use jQuery with UDFs written in javascript, to be used with BigQuery. I uploaded the jQuery library to my cloud-storage, but when I try to upload it to my UDF I'm getting an error

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined at gs://mybucket/jquery.min.js line 2, columns 7311-7312*

Any help, please?

Thank you.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION test()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js 
OPTIONS (
  library=["gs://mybucket/jquery.min.js"]
)
AS """
  return "test";
""";
```

Answer (score 1):

As you might know, some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limitations) apply to temporary and persistent user-defined functions

One of them - The DOM objects Window, Document, and Node, and **functions** that require them, are not supported.

This might be a reason!